# InnerException:System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert:IllegalParameter

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, .net-8.0, sslstream, tls1.1

InnerException :System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'IllegalParameter'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I am facing this issue while calling API from browser.
I am using Fusion for data store and using Azure function app.
Recently I am converting DotNet Core 3.1 to DotNet 8.
After migrated current project to DotNet 8. I am facing this issue.

Azure Function APP - TLS version 1.2,
Azure Storage Account - TLS version 1.2,
HTTP version- 1.1,
DotNet Version- .Net 8 Isolated,
Function Runtime Version ~4,

Please share any suggestion with me.
Thank you in Advance..!